# Convert string 10/29/2010 according to users culture

Tags: asp.net

How can I convert the english date 10/29/2010 or any language date to user culture date format

I am using the following code

```
 CultureInfo cultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.
            string lng = cultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("10/29/2010", cultureInfo);
```

but it throws error when I try to parse it.

Any Idea how can I resolve this issue

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with English (or invariant) culture to convert the String into a datetime, then you can use `ToString` to output in in the user's date format.

```
// this is in "d" (= short date) format of the invariant culture
var englishDateString = "10/29/2010"; 

// convert it to a datetime
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(englishDateString, "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// now you can output the date in the user's culture
var localizedDateString = date.ToString("d");
```

If you want to be explicit, you can add `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` as a second parameter to [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx), but it's not required, since this is the default if no culture is specified.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of parsing a US date:

```
DateTime.Parse("10/29/2010", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same pain when facing date conversion and i used a function (code below), you can modify it as you wish. try it or get ideas from it and let me know if it was useful

---

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic  Imports System.Globalization  Public Class DatumKonvert1
Public Shared Function DK1(ByVal myDMstring As String) As Date
    Dim source As String = myDMstring
    Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(source, "d'/'M'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Dim resultMydate As String = d.ToString("M'/'d'/'yyyy")
    Dim mdx = DateTime.ParseExact(resultMydate, "M'/'d'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Return mdx     End Function End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact("10/29/2010", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` instead of `DateTime.Parse`

Once you have a `DateTime`, it is no longer bound to a specific culture, but can be output however you want it.  Usually, this is with one of the DateTime `.ToString` methods, or shortcuts like [`.ToShortDateString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx), which uses the current thread's culture.

Edit: Note, it helps if I put the month and day ones in the correct spots.  Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
   public static string ChangeDateToUserFormat(string dateValue, string dateCulture)
        {
            CultureInfo dateCultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag(dateCulture);
            DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dateValue, dateCultureInfo);
            return date.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
```

For example:

```
  string date = ChangeDateToUserFormat("10\29\2010", "en-US");
```